# How can I capture the Package Version of a Dot Net Core assembly in startup code?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know that all Dot Net Core projects get marked with a package version tag that appears in the CSProj file, like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<StartupObject>MY.Program</StartupObject>
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<AssemblyName>MY.PCA</AssemblyName>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<Version>1.2.0</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there a way to get access to that Version number field at Runtime? Namely in the Startup routines found in Startup.cs?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions) package as dependency and then use `ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationVersion` property to get the version:

```
// using using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

ApplicationEnvironment app = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
string version = app.ApplicationVersion;
```

Comment: does not work for .net6.
ApplicationVersion is 0.0.0.0 although package version is set in project file (1.1.0.0)

Comment: It didn't work for me with .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Comment: You are right, but these codes are very simple, and I think they are self-documenting, that's the reason why I didn't explain them.

Comment: This returns the `Assembly Version` and not the `Package Version` as specified by `<Version>` in `.csproj` according to my testing.